# Spring Data CrudRepository.findAllById exception with large number of IDs

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jdbc

I am using the Spring Data JDBC (version 1.1.6) method `CrudRepository.findAllById` to load entities from a database with a large number of IDs. The underlying database connection uses a Postgres database. The invocation of the method raises a `PSQLException`:

```
2020-05-28 05:58:35,260 WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection [task-2] HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1224f39f marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:358)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:109)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Tried to send an out-of-range integer as a 2-byte value: 137525
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.sendInteger2(PGStream.java:275)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendParse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendOneQuery(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1876)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendQuery(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1439)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
```

The exception seem to be ultimately caused by a 16-bit limit on the number of values in the `SELECT IN (?)` clause, that is generated by Sprint Data JDBC upon using `findAllById`.

Am I supposed to partition the list of IDs myself? Shouldn't the `CrudRepository.findAllById` handle this correctly in a fashion compatible with the underlying database dialect?

Comment: No, Repository won't do that for you. Having too much parameters in your in-clause is inefficient. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I supposed to partition the list of IDs myself?

Yes, assuming this kind of query makes sense in the first place.

Spring Data JDBC currently creates a straight forward `select ... where id in (..)` query which in turn is limited by the capabilities of the underlying database/JDBC driver.

With the apparent limit being ~2<sup>16</sup> for Postgres there doesn't seem to be much need for special handling in Spring Data JDBC since looking for so many ids in a single select seems rare enough to justify some manual coding.

Comment: Note that Spring Data JDBC recommends that n-1 or n-m references should be encoded as simple ID values. This means that many related objects have to be retrieved from a repository by their ID values.

Comment: Spring Data JDBC doesn't recommend this. It requires it. Still loading 2^16 instances seems weird/wrong. I'd be interested what use case triggers this.

Comment: We have a large tree whose leaves contain ID references to other entities. We collect all the IDs in the leaves and want to retrieve them from the corresponding entity repository with a `findAllById`.